# Is this ことだ ことか?

Tags: meaning, particle-か

> ツッコミどころはいろいろあるのだが、その筆頭が挑戦する立場のBrock Lesnarに対してチャンピオンの2人（Seth RollinsとKofi Kingston）が「俺のベルトを選べ」と言ってることか。

If I translate this paragraph assuming か doesn't make the statement into a question, it would look like this:

> There's a lot of incongruencies(in the previous paragraph), but the most important is/would be  The 2 champions saying "chose my belt"(challenge for my title) to Lesnar who is in a challenger position(has a chance to challenge for any title).

The problem I have with か　is that I keep seeing it in affirmative statements like in:https://www.tripadvisor.jp/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g189143-d635293-i218411016-Old_Cathedral_of_Coimbra_Se_Velha_de_Coimbra-Coimbra_Coimbra_District_Cen.html

> 写真: “これが、ゴシック様式のポルトガル最古の回廊ということか” (this has to be an affirmative sentence and not a question or guess since that cloister from the picture is indeed the oldest in Portugal)

And since this affirmation is 100% true, why not use ことだ　instead of ことか?
If this wasn't completely true I guess you could understand か　as 'perhaps', like in 〜おかげで(thanks to/because of...) where the speaker is sure what's causing something; and 〜おかげか(perhaps/maybe thanks to/because of...) where the speaker is addressing the cause but is not completely sure if it's really the cause of something.

Is it that か sounds subjective and だ　objective?